# How to pass data from one function to another in codeigniter by using session?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Am trying to pass some data from one function to another when i set the data into session and print the session data i get the correct data, but whe trying to use the data in another function i get the word "Assets" i dont know where this word come from. Session library is auto loaded.Any help please.
These are my codes:

First function:

```
      $client_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
      $sess_array = array(
                     'cl_id' => $client_d,
                     'selected_client'=>TRUE,
                   );
     $this->session->set_userdata('selected_client',$sess_array);
```

Second function:

```
    $client_sess = $this->session->userdata('selected_client');
     $client_id= $client_sess['cl_id'];
```

Comment: Have you checked what u getting from this ?
 $client_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

Comment: where comes `$client_d` from ??

Comment: Could you call the second function from the first and pass the data then?

Answer (score 0):

Try this i think this will give you some idea.

```
function one(){
  $client_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
      $sess_array = array(
                     'cl_id' => $client_d,
                     'selected_client'=>TRUE,
                   );
    $this->two($sess_array);

}
function two($id){
   $client_id= $id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the Model looks like:

```
function getResponse($gettingresponse)

{

$enrollresponse=$gettingresponse['sendresponse'];

return $enrollresponse;

}
```

The Controller is as follows:

```
public function Register()

{

   $this->load->view('firstview');

   $this->load->view('secondview');

   if($_POST) {

       $gettingresponse=array(

           'sendresponse'=>$_POST['source'],

           'receiverresponse'=>$_POST['destination']

       );

       $registration_confirm=$this->systemModel->responselogin($gettingresponse);

       $resposeflag=$this->systemModel->getEmail($gettingresponse);

       $data['resposeflag']=$gettingresponsevalue;

       if($registration_confirm){

           $this->token($data);

       }

   }

   $this->load->view('thirdview');

}

public function token($data=array())

{

   $this->load->view('firstview');

   $data['resposeflag'];

   $this->load->view('token',$data);

   $this->load->view('thirdview');

}
```

The following View shows the data that has been passed between the functions of the Controller.

```
    <?php 
echo form_input(array('name'=>'source','readonly'=>'true','value'=>$resposeflag)); 
?>
```